# Getting IO errors while connecting a HDD to a RPi4 when using USB 3.0 but not when using USB 2

Tags: usb, pi-4, usb3

for a few weeks now, I have been suffering with the following problem:

I wanted to set up a NAS with a Raspberry Pi 4 and two WD Red, running ubuntu server, since the RPi 4 finally supports USB 3.0.
Because the HDDs need more power, I have worked from the beginning with active SATA-USB adapters.
However, a disk was always ejected and then remounted. This process was a matter of just one or two seconds and each time, the drive letter changed (sda > sdc ...). Also, each time my software raid was destroyed and the disks had to resynchronize.

While troubleshooting I stumbled across two error messages

- `over-current change #34`
- `uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 13 inflight: CMD OUT`

**The second** was UAS causing problems, so I immediately blocked it as follows:

- Create */boot/firmware/cmdline.txt*
- Add this line:  `usb-storage.quirks=174c:55aa:u`
- Update initramfs

  Now, the UAS related errors were gone.

For **the first** error, I needed some time to find out what was wrong. Afterwards it turned out that I needed an active USB hub in addition to my active SATA USB adapters to make this error message go away.

But now I still get a hard drive ejected regularly. I can't reliably reproduce the error though. What I know for sure is this:
The error messages are:

```
usb 2-1.2: reset SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
usb 2-1.2: device firmware changed
usb 2-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 4
sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Synchronizing SCSI cache
blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 114344960 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 4 prio class 0
blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 114345472 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 5 prio class 0
blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 114352128 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 22 prio class 0
sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Synchronize Cache(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
usb 2-1.2: new SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
usb 2-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=174c, idProduct=55aa, bcdDevice= 1.00
New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
usb 2-1.2: Product: ASM105x
usb 2-1.2: Manufacturer: ASMedia
usb 2-1.2: SerialNumber:      WD-WCC7K0ZET7JE
usb 2-1.2: UAS is blacklisted for this device, using usb-storage instead
usb-storage 2-1.2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
usb-storage 2-1.2:1.0: Quirks match for vid 174c pid 55aa: c00000
scsi host2: usb-storage 2-1.2:1.0
scsi 2:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ASMedia  ASM105x          0    PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
sd 2:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] 7814037168 512-byte logical blocks: (4.00 TB/3.64 TiB)
sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] 4096-byte physical blocks
sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 43 00 00 00
sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, does not support DPO or FUA
sdc: sdc1
sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI disk
md: super_written gets error=10
md: super_written gets error=10
md: super_written gets error=10
[...more lines with the same message...]
Aborting journal on device md0-8.
Buffer I/O error on dev md0, logical block 488144896, lost sync page write
JBD2: Error -5 detected when updating journal superblock for md0-8.
```

Those errors do not occur when I

- plug the active USB 3.0 Hub directly into the USB 2 ports.
- use an active USB2 hub.

From this I conclude that this problem is related to usb 3.0 on the raspberry Pi.

Currently the NAS is running on the USB 2 ports without any other errors. (Already for several days.) But i would rather not run the NAS using USB 2, as I could use USB 3 to take advantage of my gigabit connection.

**Does anyone have any idea where those errors are coming from?**

EDIT: That's the output of lsblk --fs

```
$ sudo lsblk --fs
    NAME        FSTYPE            LABEL       UUID                                 FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINT
    loop2       squashfs                                                                 0   100% /snap/snapd/11115
    sda                                                                                           
    └─sda1      linux_raid_member rpi-nas:0   7904b5e5-9f92-9402-2619-eeb41b0c0645                
      └─md0     ext4                          e5c91dcc-661e-4fb5-a431-74eaf4ae80d4    2.9T    16% /mnt/nas
    sdb         linux_raid_member rpi-nas:0   7904b5e5-9f92-9402-2619-eeb41b0c0645                
    └─md0       ext4                          e5c91dcc-661e-4fb5-a431-74eaf4ae80d4    2.9T    16% /mnt/nas
    mmcblk0                                                                                       
    ├─mmcblk0p1 vfat              system-boot 4D3B-86C0                             133.7M    47% /boot/firmware
    └─mmcblk0p2 ext4              writable    79af43d1-801b-4c28-81d5-724c930bcc83   22.5G    18% /
```

Comment: Just outta' curiosity, do you see this error when you connect only a single disk? And FWIW, I wonder if hardware RAID might be much easier?

Comment: Using only one hard drive, it runs fine as far as I have been able to observe.

Comment: I enjoy fooling around with my RPis, so this is not intended to be pessimistic, BUT: I have also seen a few, uh, "shortcomings", that wouldn't be tolerated in some systems. It seems at times that RPi is a system *"by hobbyists, for hobbyists"*, if you get my meaning.

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't solve my problem.
Could it possibly be because both hard disks (or adapters) have the same ID (174c:55aa)?

Comment: I don't know honestly - it's something I've never encountered. That might be something to investigate - assuming it's not difficult. Have you used the command `lsblk --fs` to list all block storage devices on your system? It may provide something useful - the drives need not be mounted - only "plugged-in" & powered.

Comment: lsblk --fs looks fine so far. (I've added it to my question)

Comment: I agree w/ Seamus re the actual quality of some Pi components.  I observe similar behavior w/ a Pi 4 on USB 3.0 with a small Sandisk SSD.  It isn't a huge problem for my purposes and I run a check to remount it at regular intervals, but it makes it infeasible for RAID.

Comment: The most interesting "feature" in that output is the absence of a partition for `sdb`. I would have guessed that `sda` & `sdb` would have been symmetrical? Again, I've no experience with RAID, so I'm unlikely to be useful to you. [A search](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffnt&q=RAID+on+raspberry+pi&ia=web) just now turned up [this article](https://www.ricmedia.com/build-raspberry-pi3-raid-nas-server/) which seems thorough at least. Note however that he uses USB2 instead of USB3 ports... hmmmm.

Comment: Yea, the thing is, using the usb2 ports, like I do right now, everything just works fine.
And just when using usb3 causes problems

Comment: Here's a link to an article in which the author **claims** to have set up a RAID on the USB3 ports on an RPi 4. Also, FWIW, here's what another RAID practitioner went through to get [RAID working via the PCIe interface](https://www.jeffgeerling.com/blog/2021/hardware-raid-on-raspberry-pi-cm4).

Answer (score 0):

I am experiencing similar problems from time to time. I have a [NasPI Gemini](https://geekworm.com/products/naspi-gemini?variant=39909302632536) for my pi, and I have recently added a secondary SSD to run my own Nextcloud.
I see this problem as a power source problem, because it either happens when pi has to write a lot of things to the SSD no.2. due to Nextcloud sync, or when there is a concurrent read/write from the primary SSD too.
I already replaced the power source of a 5V/2A to an 5V/3A one and now at least i don't see the "Undervoltage detected" error messages. But I still believe that with a better power source, i might not have these issues.

Now, I have a 12V/5A charger (something like [this](https://shopee.sg/AC-100V-240V-DC-Adapter-12V-2A-12V-5A-Safety-Mark-Switching-Power-Supply-UK-3-Pin-Plug-5.5mm-x-2.1mm-i.99562653.15373170470?sp_atk=5905f4cc-1f1b-4e13-9ba3-397f7a8cd174&xptdk=5905f4cc-1f1b-4e13-9ba3-397f7a8cd174)) and currently waiting for [my step-down module](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005004686103912.html) (to 5V/5A) to arrive and I will connect the whole system in that way. If it helps, I will let you know guys.